# Iterate through child elements one by one with setTimeout or delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `div`s and I want to iterate through them applying a CSS filter in a delayed manner.

I currently have attempted this

```
$(this).children().each(function() {
    $(this).delay(5000).css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(2)");
});
```

And this

```
$i = 0;
 $(this).children().each(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(2)");
     }, $i * 500);
     $i++ 
});
```

The first one doesn't give any delay. The second one applies the delay to the last in the group (the .each())

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raaexs2m/

Comment: check the updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/raaexs2m/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/raaexs2m/1/). 1. FIxed sortable issue in first answer. 2. Actual issue- Explanation is as mentioned in the second answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your second approach was, that "this" in the anonymous setTimeout function is not anymore the same "this" you're expecting.

The solution I used:
just reassign the "this" before calling setTimout like this:

```
var mythis = this;
```

mythis will now be accessable within the anonymous function of setTimeout.

```
$i = 0;
 $(this).children().each(function() {
     var mythis = this; // << introducing mythis
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(mythis).css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(2)"); // << using mythis
     }, $i * 500);
     $i++ 
});
```

Comment: You assign a variable but then never use it?